# How to run ansible playbooks with subprocess

Tags: python, ansible, subprocess

I am new to ansible and no matter what I have tried I am failing to call a simple playbook through a python script.

Sample of code:

```py
import subprocess


def sample(host, user):
    cmd = ["ansible-playbook",
           "-i {},".format(host),
           "-e ansible_user={}".format(user),
           "sample.yml",
           "-v"]

    subprocess.run(cmd)


def main():
    sample("hostname,", "user")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Sample of STDOUT:

```sh
PLAY [all] *********************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] *********************************************************
```

The script remains like this until I terminate it.

When I execute the ansible play book from command line `$ ansible-playbook sample.yml -i "hostname," -e "user=user"` I get the expected STDOUT:

```sh
PLAY [all] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [hostname]

TASK [debug] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [hostname] => {
    "msg": "I'm on hostname"
}

PLAY RECAP **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
hostname              : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

My goal is to overwrite the groups with a single host this is why I am using the syntax `-i "hostname,"`.

Sample of the sample.yml file:

```py
---
- hosts: all
  remote_user: '{{ ansible_user }}'
  any_errors_fatal: true
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "I'm on {{ ansible_host }}"
```

Where I am going so wrong?

Comment: Unfortunately I can only give you a "Works For Me", but that must mean there is something else going on here. Is there any more relevant information you can provide?

Comment: @MattP I was testing on WSL node and also on LinuxOS. I was able to get it working on my LinuxOS but not on my WSL. The only working solution on both nodes for me is posted below. Thank you for your time and effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the only thing that managed to make it work for both WSL and also LinuxOS is:

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3

import pprint
import subprocess
import sys


def sample(host, user):
    cmd = ["ansible-playbook",
           "-i {},".format(host),
           "-e ansible_user={}".format(user),
           "-e ANSIBLE_HOST_KEY_CHECKING=False",
           "sample.yml",
           "-v"]

    proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd,
                            stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                            stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                            )

    try:
        outs, errs = proc.communicate(timeout=15)
        pprint.pprint(outs.decode().split('\n'))
    except subprocess.SubprocessError as errs:
        proc.kill()
        sys.exit("Error: {}".format(errs))

def main():
    sample("hostname", "user")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

You can simply execute it as:

```sh
$ python3 test.py
['Using /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg as config file',
 '',
 'PLAY [all] '
 '*********************************************************************',
 '',
 'TASK [Gathering Facts] '
 '*********************************************************',
 'ok: [hostname]',
 '',
 'TASK [debug] '
 '*******************************************************************',
 'ok: [hostname] => {',
 '    "msg": "I\'m on hostname"',
 '}',
 '',
 'PLAY RECAP '
 '*********************************************************************',
 'hostname              : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    '
 'failed=0   ',
 '',
 '']
```

**UPDATE:** In case you want to have compatibility with both Python2 and Python3 the code needs to be minimized a bit:

```py
import pprint
import subprocess
import sys


def sample(host, user):
    cmd = ["ansible-playbook",
           "-i {},".format(host),
           "-e ansible_user={}".format(user),
           "-e ANSIBLE_HOST_KEY_CHECKING=False",
           "sample.yml",
           "-v"]

    proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd,
                            stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                            stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                            )

    try:
        if sys.version_info > (3, 0):
            # Python 3 code in this block
            outs, errs = proc.communicate(timeout=15)
            pprint.pprint(outs.decode().split('\n'))
        else:
            # Python 2 code in this block
            outs, errs = proc.communicate()
            pprint.pprint(outs.decode().split('\n'))
    except subprocess.SubprocessError as errs:
        proc.kill()
        sys.exit("Error: {}".format(errs))


def main():
    sample("hostname", "user")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Then simply you can test with the following:

```py
$ python test.py
['Using /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg as config file',
 '',
 'PLAY [all] *********************************************************************',
 '',
 'TASK [Gathering Facts] *********************************************************',
 'ok: [hostname]',
 '',
 'TASK [debug] *******************************************************************',
 'ok: [hostname] => {',
 '    "msg": "I\'m on hostname"',
 '}',
 '',
 'PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************',
 'hostname              : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0   ',
 '',
 '']
```

For Python3 simply:

`````py
$ python3 test.py
['Using /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg as config file',
 '',
 'PLAY [all] '
 '*********************************************************************',
 '',
 'TASK [Gathering Facts] '
 '*********************************************************',
 'ok: [hostname]',
 '',
 'TASK [debug] '
 '*******************************************************************',
 'ok: [hostname] => {',
 '    "msg": "I\'m on hostname"',
 '}',
 '',
 'PLAY RECAP '
 '*********************************************************************',
 'hostname              : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    '
 'failed=0   ',
 '',
 '']
````

One problem that I have noticed here a minor problem is that [pycharm][1] installed on WindowsOS and running with Python2/3 2/3 Ubuntu wsl://UBUNTU/usr/bin/python is unfortunately stays frozen as shown above, but if you execute the code from terminal everything works as expected.

I have installed WSL not WSL2 maybe this problem is fixed on WSL2.


  [1]: https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/
`````

Answer (score 1):

The passing of command-line arguments is missing. See [sys.argv](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/sys.html#sys.argv). The rest of the code is fine.

```
from sys import argv
import subprocess
[...]

def main():
    script, hostname, user = argv
    sample(hostname, user)
[...]
```

---

Notes

1) To test the playbook the extra argument should be *`ansible_user`*

```
$ ansible-playbook sample.yml -i "hostname," -e "ansible_user=user"
```

2) With `sample("hostname,", "user")` the playbook has always run at `"hostname"` as `"user"`

3) It is possible to use `-l` instead of `-i` and avoid the coma

```
$ ansible-playbook sample.yml -l "hostname" -e "ansible_user=user"
```

4) Take a look at [Ansible Runner](https://ansible-runner.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Comment: Thanks a lot Vladimir for your time. Unfortunately in my case the only way to make it work was to use `subprocess.Popen` so I could capture the exceptions. I was not able to understand why on my LinuxOS box was working but not on the WSL node.